# how does this line function: require_once('Zend/Registry.php');?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have installed Zend Framework 2(Zend Framework + Zend Server) on my win 7.
In `Zend/Apache2/htdocs/hello1.php`, I put below script:

```
<?php
    require_once('Zend/Registry.php'); 
    $registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance(); 
    $registry['name'] = 'Quentin Zervaas'; 
    echo sprintf('My name is %s', $registry['name']);
?>
```

Then I run `http://localhost/hello1.php`, it shows:
My name is Quentin Zervaas

My question is:
for this line `require_once('Zend/Registry.php');` under htdocs folder, it is dummy.php, favicon.ico, index.html,hello1.php,
there is no Zend folder, so how does this line function?

Comment: Must be environment variables game.

Comment: That's because Zend is installed somewhere on your include path. You can see your include_path doing a var_dump of get_include_path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In you php.ini check this

```
include_path
```

it would have the default location of your zend directory.

Comment: You are right. In D:\program files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\etc\php.ini, there is a line:
...
[Zend]
include_path=".;D:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library"
...

But what does this '.;'(in double quotation marks) mean?

Comment: .; is Windows include_path. Using a . in the include path allows for relative includes as it means the current directory. However, it is more efficient to explicitly use include './file' than having PHP always check the current directory for every include. More info here http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Zend Framework 2 - you should not be using Zend_Registry.  That is a ZF 1 component not a ZF 2 component.  The only reason it is working is because your include path and Zend Server puts ZF 1 in there.